# didReceiveMemoryWarning, viewDidUnload

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was reading a book, which suggested that declaring my `IBOutlets` as `weak` should take care of the issue when my app gets low memory warning. e.g., I would *not* need to set these outlets to nil now in the `viewDidUnload` method anymore.

I also heard in iOS6 `viewDidUnload` is deprecated and instead `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called.

Anyway, how shall I go on, shall I declare my `IBOutlet`s as `weak`, and "forget" about implementing `didReceiveMemoryWarnings` and `viewDidUnloads`?

Comment: didReceiveMemoryWarning does not replace viewDidUnload, it was already present in older versions. If you want to keep compatibility with iOS prior 6 you should continue using viewDidUnload

Comment: Ok, but also next to Apurv's answer, I think I will not have to implement any of the two methods, if I am concerned only with IBOutlets (I will set them as weak). This concerns both iOS5 and 6 right?

Answer (score 2):

Not all `IBOutlets` should be made `weak`. Recommendation from [Apple docs (Resource Programming guide)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW6)

> Outlets should generally be weak, except for those from File’s Owner to top-level objects in a nib file (or, in iOS, a storyboard scene) which should be strong. Outlets that you create should therefore typically be weak, because:
>
> - Outlets that you create to, for example, subviews of a view controller’s view or a window controller’s window, are arbitrary references between objects that do not imply ownership.
> - The strong outlets are frequently specified by framework classes (for example, UIViewController’s view outlet, or NSWindowController’s window outlet).

Example:

Top level objects in your XIB should be declared `strong`, any other subviews/controls should be made `weak` properties.

> ```
>     @property (nonatomic, weak)   IBOutlet MyView *viewContainerSubview;
>     @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MyOtherClass *topLevelObj;
> ```

Using ARC `weak` lifetime qualifier has its own advantages([Refer Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4)) because,

> __weak specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive. A weak reference is set to nil when there are no strong references to the object.

So you need not worry about setting the `IBOutlets` `nil`, its lifetime is automatically bound by its top level instance.

`didReceiveMemoryWarning` should be implemented to clear any recreatable resources which are hogging the memory. When you receive the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` call, it should be used to release non-critical resources that are used ex: custom data structures, webservice response used to populate the UI etc. The non-criticality of any resource needs to be decided by the developer.

Comment: Hi Amar, yes indeed I knew about the top level view objects.

Comment: Cool, thought i'd mention in case.

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use IBOutlet as weak. When you declare them as strong, in case of low memory condition, you might need to handle to clear them in viewDidUnload method.

However there are many more objects apart from Outlets which can also be removed from memory in case of memory issues. So, if the program is having outlets as weak, you just need to consider the cached data objects and noting else.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

*Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of low-memory conditions through its **didReceiveMemoryWarning** method, which releases unneeded memory.*

*Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the UIViewController class purged its views if it knew it could reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the **viewWillUnload** and **viewDidUnload** methods to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the **didReceiveMemoryWarning** method.*

Therefore, no need to set any of your IBOutlet references to nil anywhere, because the views are no longer purged. It would make no sense to set them to nil in didReceiveMemoryWarning or anything like that.But, in case you were responding to low memory events by releasing easily-recreated model objects, emptying caches, etc., in viewDidUnload, then that stuff should definitely move to didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Answer (score 0):

Views are no longer automatically unloaded on memory warnings since iOS6. This doesn't mean that memory use is no longer of any concern of course, you can't just 'forget' about it.

IBOutlets should generally be `weak`, since they are (directly or indirectly) 'owned' by the viewcontroller's view. And usually you want their lifetimes to be the same as their parent view.

You should still try to clear as much memory as possible in didReceiveMemoryWarning. (memory of assets that are not currently used and can be recreated of course)

Comment: Hi Pieter, so I assume your answer is similar to Apurv's? I can forget about IBOutlets if they are set as weak, and I can **think** to release other data objects. You mention "recreating" -- when/where does my app get this chance to **recreate**?

Comment: (this all assumes iOS6+) yes, set IBOutlets itself as weak, and let the system handle view loading / unloading. A recreating example would be that e.g. you show images, and you write a not currently visible image to disk and release it's memory (as you can read the file again and display the image if you want to show it again later)

Comment: Pieter why did you mention "this all assumes iOS6+" what assumes iOS6+? thanks.

Comment: in iOS5, and prior, your views will always be unloaded on memory warning